# Add border to Googlesheet based on nth row conditioning

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a large spreadsheet, and so I have been adding a bottom boarder every 10th row, but not in conditioning. So every time I change the sheet, I have to redo the borders.

Is there a way to condition the sheet to recognise every 10th row (exluding the first due to headers) and then add a border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (to the best of my knowledge) Google Sheets doesn't support cell borders in conditional formatting - the nearest you could get is a custom formula like this:

```
=mod(row()-1,10)=0
```

and then add a coloured border at rows 11,21,31 etc.

[image]

```
=and(mod(row()-1,10)=0,row()>1)
```

to exclude the headers row.